# Open new browser windows in JavaScript without making it active

Tags: javascript, firefox, popup

I have some JavaScript that makes an AJAX call and, if the call fails, opens a new windows (tab in Firefox) and displays the response from the server in that window. This is very convenient for debugging, because the error is typically from Pylons, so it's a full HTML page.

The only problem is that the new tab becomes the active tab, which would totally confuse a regular user. Is there any way to open the tab/window, but not make it active, ie. keep the current active window?

My code currently looks like this:

```
    errorWindow = window.open("", "TCerrorWindow")
    if (errorWindow)
        errorWindow.document.write(xhr.responseText);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would a regular user interested to see the server response? If it is for debugging as you said, turn it off in production.

Comment: Why would you show that to your customer? Write the information to an div in your page and hide that. Then show an error Information IN your page and show the customer a contact possibilty for help. There you could add an little icon for expand information which will show the html page of the error. Only if the user like's your help he should see the debug information.

Comment: This depends on the user's configuration anyway. I have both Safari and Firefox set up to open new windows in a new tab, but keep focus on the current tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `errorWindow.blur(); window.focus();` after, forcing the browser to return focus to the previous window.

The effect you're trying to achieve is commonly called a [pop-under window](http://www.web-source.net/popunder.htm).

Comment: This works in IE8 and works in Firefox if a new WINDOW is opened (by specifying a window size in window.open). It doesn't work with tabs, but I suppose there's no way to do that, so I'm accepting your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK this is not possible, as a security measure against pop-under windows. For debugging purposes you could

- use Firebug (with a handy console, where you can output your own log messages from the code)
- create a debug layer (div) on your page, where you output error messages in case an error happens